# How can I convert a date string from Mongoose Query?

Tags: javascript, date, mongoose

My Mongoose date query return the below string:

`24th Jun 2015`

How to convert it to javascript date object?

Comment: what is your query like? Why do not you have the string stored as date while writing?

Comment: sorry, I am using `keystone.js` CMS and it uses a customized `format` method and changed the date format. This is not the original mongoose query output.

Comment: I have found the solution by using `moment.js`:
`moment("24th Dec 2015", "DD MMM YYYY").format("M/D/YYYY");var date = 
alert(date);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want parse the mongodb result, use `moment.js` to convert String to date : http://momentjs.com/.

```
var date = moment("24th June 2015", "Do MMM YYYY"); // you've got a moment Date
```

If you want convert this MongoDb String to date for queries, convert a date with monent.js to this String format and use it in Query :

```
var date = moment().format('Do MMM YYYY'); // return 18th Jun 2015 for today
```

Comment: I think you got it incorrect. He has the date in the format already, he wants it to be as a date object in js.